# java how open file to write

Tags: java, file-io, character-encoding

I want to write a file but mixture of 3 bellow feature. how?

1. BufferedWriter , high volume data write needed
2. can append to exist text file
3. can set charset like "cp1256"

How mix all these features to open write file?

Answer (score 0):

What you would do first is, Initiate your `BufferedWriter` :

`

```
    String fileName = METHOD ARGUMENT, OR REGULAR STRING ("Output.txt");
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {

       File outFile = new File(fileName);

           writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(OUTPUT NAME OF THE FILE YOU ARE WRITING. , true)); 
           writer.write(WHAT YOU WANT TO WRITE TO THE FILE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            // Close the writer regardless of what happens...
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Now to explain the code so I'm not just spoon feeding it to you. 
When we declare the `BufferedWriter writer = null;` , we are setting it to null so that we don't write anything without setting a Try/Catch Exception Handler around it.

Once we are within our exception handled, we initiate a `File` called outFile. This will be the file we are outputting. The Argument we give it is the name of the file name. (A `String` Value such as, "Output.txt") NOTE: You MUST add the extension or else it won't work the way you are hoping it does.

Next, when we reference our `BufferedWriter` again, we initiate a new one in the try/catch handler, and inside we initiate a FileWriter (What will be doing the writing to the file). We give it two arguments. The name of the Output File("Output.txt"), and we also supply a `true` argument. What this does is makes the File Appendable! When we write true, we are saying we want the file to be appendable.

Finally, we write to the file, whatever it is you want to write.

As for the third feature, I don't think that `FileWriter`'s will allow you to choose the Character Encoding that you want to write with, so unless you aren't using UTF-8, then you may want to use a `PrintWriter`

To do this, you would simply replace our `writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(OUTPUT NAME OF THE FILE YOU ARE WRITING. , true));

`writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(outputName, "UTF-8"));`

I THINK this should work, if not, please let me know, I'll find a working solution.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I mix FileWriter's overwrite flag and PrinterWriter's charset feature at same time?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class WriteFile {
BufferedWriter out;
public void openFile(String file){
    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.txt"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void writeInts(int[] ints){
    try {
        for(int i : ints) out.write(i+" ");
        out.newLine();
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void closeFile(){
    try {
        if (out!=null)out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

}

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    WriteFile wf = new WriteFile();
    wf.openFile("test.txt");
    wf.writeInts(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5});
    wf.writeInts(new int[]{5,4,3,2,1});
    wf.closeFile();
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
    System.out.println(bf.readLine());
    System.out.println(bf.readLine());
}
```

}

Output:
Line1: 1 2 3 4 5 
Line2: 5 4 3 2 1

Comment: Please explain why your code is helpful. That will improve your answer a lot!

Comment: Output:
data.txt file would be created and 
Line1 in data.txt has: 1 2 3 4 5 
Line2 in data.txt has: 5 4 3 2 1